# TIme series decomposition using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, stl-decomposition

I'm using `R` with the `forecast package` to build some time-series models.
Right now, i'm dealing with multiple-seasonality data, using the `tbats` function.

When a plot the fitted-model, i get a plot with the time-series components. My question is, what does exactly the `slope` component means? (I couldn't find it in the docs).

Code:

```
fit <- tbats(co2, use.trend= TRUE, use.box.cox = TRUE, seasonal.periods = c(12))
plot(fit)
```

Thanks![image]

Comment: The slope is the first derivative of the trend.

Comment: Thanks! But i don't get why it's always positive, even when the trend seems to fall...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slope m indicates the trend. You probably want to use the [stl](http://www.r-bloggers.com/seasonal-trend-decomposition-in-r/) or [decompose](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/decompose.html) functions in R to derive the slope and season.

The general equation for decomposition is x(t)=s(t)+m(t)+e(t) where t is time, m is slope or trend, s is season and e is the error term for residuals.

Seasonality is the periodic fluctuations and trend is a generalized direction over a given time